# Boosting of Coset diagrams

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, computational-algebra

[image]

If we have the diagram that represents a transitive permutation representation of $(p,q,r_o)$ for some $p, q$ and $r_o$,  we often use this diagram to get diagrams for any $r>r_o$. We can do this by adding y-arcs in each face of the diagram. The process of addung y-arcs is termed boosting.

In this diagram th vertices joined by any x-arcs(that is fixed point of x) are called free vertices. These free vertices can be used to atach new x-arcs that will "boost" the diagram.

Here we suppose that there are *i* consecutive free vertices on a q-gon say *Q*. By using x-arcs we  can join them with *p-i* free vertices of another q-gon, Say $Q'$. As the q-gons and x-arcs both are oreinted in anticlockwise directions, we get there are *i-1* vertices of *Q* and *p-i-1* vertices of *Q'* fixed by *xy* as in this figure above.

Now I am confused in one thing that after adding a q-gon, we get $q-(i-1+p-i-1)=q-p+2$ new *y-arcs* in the face to which *Q'* was added? Thus , the length of the cucle of *xy* corresponding to the face is incresed by *q-p+2*?

As far as I understand, Given before boosting D is the diagram for $<x,y: x^p=y^q=(xy)^r=1>$ We knoe thar each of $a_1,a_2,...,a_q$ in Q gon and $b_1,..b_q$ must be fixed by $(xy)^r$.

We know than $a_1,...,a_i$ are fixed by x, and $ b_1,..,b_{p-i}$ are fixed by x, This tell us something about the cycle for *xy* . When we add new x-edges $a_1$ to $b_{p-i}$ and $b_1$ to $a_i$ then what happens to xy- cucles that it is increased by *r+(q-p+2)*. How?

Comment: could you please add the reference to the book or paper from which the image is above taken?

Comment: This text is taken by Sajida Kousar PhD Thesis "Alternating Quotients of Non Euclidean Cyrstallographic Groups" University of York, 2013. However, this method has also been defined in Brent Everitt's paper Alternating Quotients of Fuchsian Groups J. Algebra 2000. no 2. 457-476

Comment: thanks. And why are you asking this under (gap) tag? Perhaps (computational-algebra) tag instead of (gap) would be more appropriate.

Comment: PhD thesis from 2013 and a 20-pages long paper from a journal... could this be more appropriate for [Mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/)?

Comment: I am working on its examples, most probably now I have an understanding on Boosting. Soon I will answer this question with its example.

Comment: Hi I am Sajida Kousar and this is a diagram from first draft of my thesis. On type k-pendent the number of vertices included are p-i not p-2i+1.

Comment: @Sajida Kausar right, you mean here that you add p-i vertices in the original diagram but value of r=order(xy) is increased by p-2i+1 after adding k- pendant?